# How can I compare the hour to a string/number in bash?

Tags: bash

We have a server which we use to run Selenium tests with our extension (for Chrome and Firefox). We run the Selenium tests every 2 hours. I want to run different tests after 14:00 than before 14:00. I have this variable:

```
start_hour=`TZ='Asia/Tel_Aviv' date +"%H"`
```

And I know how to compare it to a specific hour, such as 08:00 AM (it's a string):

```
if [ "$start_hour" = "08" ]; then
    ...
fi
```

But how do I check if this variable shows an hour after 14:00 (including 14:00), or before 14:00? Can I compare strings in bash and how? I just want to check if `$start_hour` is >= "14", or not?

Is the answer different if I want to check after 08:00 AM or before?

Comment: There's no reason to quote the 8 -- it's a constant, so will never be prone to string-splitting and glob expansion (which quoting prevents). What you should be quoting is your variable expansions; thus, `"$start_hour"`, not $start_hour.

Comment: BTW, you probably *don't* want a leading `0` in your `08`. This can request octal interpretation, and only digits 0-7 can be parsed as octal.

Comment: I'd consider generalizing this question to be about greater/less-than numeric integer comparisons in bash in general, by the way -- there's no reason to make it specifically about hours.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I want to compare $start_hour with the string "08".

Comment: ...so you want an ASCII-sort string comparison, not a numeric comparison? **Why?**

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't mind how I compare as long as it works. Currently the expression `if [ $start_hour = "08" ]; then` works.

Comment: One of the things about bash is that using the wrong syntax can result in subtle bugs -- ones you only see in unusual conditions. For instance, if you had an empty `start_hour` (maybe `date` didn't run for some reason), `if [ $start_hour = "08" ]` will parse as `if [ = 08 ]`, which will report a syntax error, vs (more correctly) reporting that `""` is not a number.

Comment: if `start_hour='1 -eq 1 -o 08'`, you'd also get a truthy outcome from your existing code with the inadequate quoting... so, "X works for me, and I don't wanna change it" is, in general, an approach better kept for languages with stronger static checking, such that you have more reason to believe "works for me" has a strong correspondance with "is actually correct".

Comment: (Speaking of static checking, see -- and consider running your code through -- http://shellcheck.net/)

Comment: BTW, bash 4.3 has built-in `strftime` support in its `printf` operator, so you can get rid of the use of the external `date` command at all if that's what you're targeting.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I updated my question.

Comment: *nod*. `"08"` and `08` are still equivalent (both are interpreted as strings except in a numeric context, and interpreted as numbers when in a numeric context), but the quotes don't hurt anything; they simply don't help anything either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To perform greater or less-than comparisons, the `test` operations `-gt`, `-le`, `-ge`, and `-le` exist.

```
start_hour=$(TZ='Asia/Tel_Aviv' date '+%k')
[ "$start_hour" -ge 8 ]
```

Note the use of `%k` vs `%H`, and `8` vs `08` -- a leading 0 can prevent your numbers from being interpreted as decimal.

Similarly, in native bash syntax, for a numeric comparison:

```
start_hour=$(TZ='Asia/Tel_Aviv' date '+%k')
(( start_hour >= 8 ))
```

---

If your shell is bash, and *not* /bin/sh, and you truly do want an ASCII-sort string comparison, you can use `>` and `<` inside of `[[ ]]`:

```
start_hour=$(TZ='Asia/Tel_Aviv' date '+%H')
[[ $start_hour > 08 || $start_hour = 08 ]]
```

Comment: Notice that $start_hour is always 2 digits. If the hour is 08:00 AM then it's "08".

Comment: @Uri, yes, but `08` **isn't a valid number**, because the leading 0 makes it parse as octal. Thus, if you want to compare `08`, you need to do so as a string, not a number.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and let you know if it works. I don't mind to compare strings, or numbers, it doesn't matter because 2-digit strings always compare the same as the numbers.

Comment: Do you mean `if [[ $start_hour >= 08 ]]; then`?

Comment: If you want to put an `if` around it, sure. `[[`, like `[`, isn't `if`-specific syntax; it's a command, like any other, and like any other command `if` can operate on its exit status.

Comment: ...you could run `[[ $start_hour >= 08 ]] && [[ $start_hour < 17 ]] && { echo "we're open"; }`, for instance. You could (while it's bad practice) collect `$?` and inspect that. Etc.

Comment: (Note that failing to quote `$start_hour` is acceptable *specifically inside `[[ ]]`*, as it creates a context in which glob expansion and string-splitting are disabled; even there, there are a few places, such as the right-hand side of an `=` or `=~` operation, where quotes have meaning).

Comment: I'm sorry, `if [[ $start_hour >= 14 ]]; then` doesn't work (with or without quotes in both sides) - I get this error: `syntax error near `14'`.

Comment: @Uri, this implies that your shell isn't bash. `sh yourscript` runs it with a POSIX sh interpreter, not with bash; `[[ ]]` is syntax only available in ksh derivatives, bash among them.

Comment: The script starts with `#!/bin/bash`, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I changed to "start_hour_decimal=`TZ='Asia/Tel_Aviv' date +"%k"`" and `if (( start_hour_decimal >= 14 )); then` and it works, but `if [[ $start_hour >= 14 ]]; then` didn't work. Before I accept this answer I want to see that it works.

Comment: Amended appropriately.